# Generar una expresión regular que extraiga el 01 de este nombre de archivo AVALUO_0001_01.pdf

Tags: regex

quisiera consultar sobre si me pueden ayudar con una expresión regular que pueda extraer el siguiente dato: AVALUO_0001_**01**.pdf (es el 01 que viene en este nombre de archivo) el formato normal de como vendría el archivo es el que les comento anteriormente y necesito extraer ese valor (01) porque es el número de versión del archivo.

Estaré Muy agradecido.

Saludos a todos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Los ficheros siempre son pdf? Los nombres siempre siguen ese formato o podrían tener otra nomenclatura? (algo como `AVALUO33.X_0001_01.pdf`)

Comment: Podrían cambiar, disculpa la demora pero podrían llegarte estos casos AVALUO_21_02 ,  AVALUO_121_0001 ,  AVALUO_124_0229 , AVALUO_131_01 , AVALUO_141_01983 , AVALUO_211_000001 , AVALUO_234_00101 , AVALUO_9298_82737 así podrían venir necesito extraer ambos números por separado, necesito ayuda.

Comment: El punto '.' se puede dar en el nombre del fichero? (por ejemplo AVALUO.88_123_123.pdf? La extensión siempre es pdf?

Comment: Si siempre es pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar **regex101.com** para probar tus expresiones regulares.

La forma de conseguir lo que quieres es usando grupos. Checa mi ejemplo.

```
var buscar = "AVALUO_9876_011231233.pdf", 
    regex = /([0-9]+).pdf/g, 
    match = regex.exec(buscar);
console.log(match[1]);
```

La expresión está buscando todo lo que sean 1 o mas números ([0-9]+) seguidos de .pdf. 
   Al rodearlos de parentesis estoy indicando que son grupos. el grupo 1 entonces son los números.

Espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: Podrían cambiar, disculpa la demora pero podrían llegarte estos casos AVALUO_21_02 ,  AVALUO_121_0001 ,  AVALUO_124_0229 , AVALUO_131_01 , AVALUO_141_01983 , AVALUO_211_000001 , AVALUO_234_00101 , AVALUO_9298_82737 así podrían venir necesito extraer ambos números por separado, necesito ayuda.

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es usar esta expresion /([0-9]+)(.pdf)/g

Comment: No se a que refieres con los dos números por separado. Si te refieres a los que están antes del guión bajo y antes del .pdf, yo lo haría así.

Comment: var buscar = "AVALUO_9876_011231233.pdf",
    regex = /([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).pdf/g;
    console.log(match[1], ' ', match[2]);

Comment: Si exacto, muchas gracias, era la referencia que buscaba

Comment: @NicolasLopezVasquez, puedes aceptar la respuesta de Cesar, si te ha servido

Comment: @NicolasLopezVasquez te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: @cesargroening soy novato en esto, si me puedes decir como aceptar la respuesta y disculpa por la tardanza.